# Problems when viewing certain websites after installing Arial font. Persists after removal

Tags: fonts

I've installed Arial recently, and it created a problem in the proper display of certains webpages. Maybe the font was "incomplete", for it wouldn't display French accentuated characters (see screencap attached). I removed the ttf file, but the problem persists.

How can I install or remove the Arial font properly?

I'm using a PC with LMDE2, cinnamon edition.

Thanks

[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqZB5.png)

Comment: Windows, Mac, Linux? Version?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot! Edited post.

Comment: Nevermind, found answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/651441/how-to-install-arial-font-in-ubuntu